# Send Multiple Values to Mysql Query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, checklistbox

Here Is the Story :

I have a checked list which has items from my database need to write a query to get only the selected items details which will then populate the gridviwe

```
 object[] items = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToArray();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {



            string connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=admin;database=per_update;";
            string query = "select * from tblcenters where centerName in('" + item + "')";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);


                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                }
```

}
}

i wrote this code it only gets me the details about the last item that I select. but I need the details to all the items i select

please don't worry about not using parameters in  query since this is a sample

Comment: But you should always use parameters to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @BugFinder . . . Then explain how the OP can use parameters for an `IN` list.  Unfortunately, this is one of those cases where using parameters is not simple.

Comment: What does `item` look like? I mean the content of one of it

Comment: @rbr94 Yakkala, Maharagama,Malabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build the string you have to use in the `WHERE IN` statement like this:

```
var whereValues = "";

foreach (var item in items) {
    whereValues += ", '" + item + "'";
}

whereValues += whereValues.Substring(2, whereValues.Length-2);

string query = "select * from tblcenters where centerName in(" + whereValues + ")";
```

Comment: this worked with some amendments whereValues += ", " + " ' "  +item+ " ' " ;

Comment: Yes if your values are of type string. I forgot to consider that. I edited my post.

Comment: I would add that this solution has two potential errors. It returns also rows that have an empty string in the _centerName_ column and I hope you never have values with embedded quotes.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your hint! Therefore I cut off the first to chars of `whereValues` and intialize `whereValues` with `string.Empty` instead of `''`. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**.
Maybe you should use a `StringBuilder` for this task. Also it is very inefficient if you do a request for each selected item.
Something like the following might be a better solution:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("select * from tblcenters where centerName in(");
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
  sb.Append('" + item[i] + "' + ",");
}
sb.Length--; // to get rid of the last comma (',')
sb.Append(")");
string query = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Please use the statement, which is given in the question to demonstrate your purpose. It might be confusing to some users, because it lacks the direct context.

Comment: @rbr94 Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

```
object[] items = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<object>().ToArray();
string InStatement="("; //prepare the in clause
foreach (var item in items)
{
   InStatement+=item+",";

}
InStatement=InStatement.Substring(0, InStatement.Length - 1)+")";///trim last comma and add ending parenthesis
string connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=admin;database=per_update;";
string query = "select * from tblcenters where centerName in"+InStatement;
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
    {
      DataTable ds = new DataTable();
      adapter.Fill(ds);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the resetting of the item value inside your loop.
You say that it is not required to use parameters, but in cases like this it is not really too complicated to use them and have a safer code

```
// Get all the checked items in a list of strings...
List<string> values = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();

List<MySqlParameter> prms = new List<MySqlParameter>();
List<string> prmsNames = new List<string>();

// Loop over the values and build the parameter names and the parameters
for (int x = 0; x < values.Count; x++)
{
    // The parameter with a conventional name
    prms.Add(new MySqlParameter("@" + x.ToString(), MySqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = values[x] });
    // the parameter' names
    prmsNames.Add("@" + x.ToString());
}

// The command text
string query = @"select * from tblcenters 
                 where centerName in (" + 
                string.Join(",", prmsNames) + ")";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
{
    // Add the parameters collection to the select command....
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}
```